# Database architecture for collecting day-to-day information

Tags: database-design

I am wondering what would be the best solution to implement a simple database that will contain day-to-day information, that is, NHL hockey statistics. Of course I thought of a `Player` table and a `Team` table, which will contain up to date statistics for each players and teams. My main concern is that I would like to be able to store statistics on any given day of the season, so it will be possible to compare statistics of a given player in a date range. To do this, I thought of creating a table for each player which would contain rows for each day of the season. This solution might be interesting, but considering there are over 500 players in the NHL, this would result in too many tables. My question is, how could I design my database schema according to my needs?

I will be using SQL Server 2008 R2 along with ASP.NET MVC 3 and the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1.  Buy Ralph Kimball's Data Warehouse Toolkit book.

Step 2.  Read about the "Star Schema".

Step 3.  Design a star schema with your facts (measurable quantities) with dimensions (player, team, time, game).

It's pretty straightforward -- after you know how  Star Schema works.

Comment: are we still talking about relational databases?

Comment: @JFB.  Step 1.  Buy the book.  The answer is "yes".  A star schema is a design approach.